# How do the timelines between Black Panther and Captain America: Civil War interact?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, chronology, captain-america-civil-war, black-panther

At the start of the present day in *Black Panther* when T'Challa extracts Nakia from her operation, he tells her that his father, King T'Chaka, died and he wants her to come to his coronation ceremony. I was under the impression that T'Challa has his coronation ceremony in *Black Panther* within a day-or-two of T'Chaka dying in the bombing, but he also seems to immediately go after Bucky Barnes in *Civil War*, which seems to cover a few days.

Do the events in *Black Panther* and *Captain America: Civil War* overlap at all? Or does one movie's present day take place entirely after the other one?

Comment: I definitely got the impression that he had been home for a short time, and left again to go Nakia, and that there was a decent period in between. Note that, for example, T'Challa's mother doesn't seem to be in shock or heavily mourning by the time the movie starts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Comicbook.com,

> During this time, the only superhumans we know to be active are Black
>   Panther (Wakandan monarch T'Chaka, played by Atandwa Kani), and
>   possibly Captain Marvel (a yet-to-be-introduced Brie Larson).
>
> Her debut film, out in 2019, is set sometime during the 1990s —
>   decades after Captain America (Chris Evans), Ant-Man (Michael
>   Douglas), and Wasp (Michelle Pfeiffer) gave rise to the current crop
>   of Earth's mightiest heroes operating in modern day.
>
> Of course, a brash and bratty Thor (Chris Hemsworth) is somewhere off
>   world, not yet the hero he would come to be in 2011's Thor.
>
> **The 1992 prologue sees a radicalized N'Jobu (Sterling K. Brown) come into conflict with his brother T'Chaka before Black Panther jumps to
>   one week after the events of Captain America: Civil War, which
>   introduced T'Challa (Chadwick Boseman) as a vengeful king-to-be
>   seeking justice for his murdered father.**
>
> That also puts Black Panther taking place before last summer's
>   Spider-Man: Homecoming. A title card early on in the movie has us
>   catching up with Peter Parker (Tom Holland) "two months later" after
>   his scuffle with the Avengers at a German airport.
>
> Thor: Ragnarok, if you're wondering, takes place roughly around the
>   same time as Homecoming...
>
> For your recommended eventual Marvel Studios chronological marathon,
>   you would follow Civil War with Black Panther, Homecoming, and then
>   Ragnarok, with the mid-credits scene of the latter heading directly
>   into Avengers: Infinity War.
>   http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/02/17/black-panther-MCU-timeline-phase-three/

Comment: if you pay attention when the scene opens, the news report T'Challa is watching in his jet say it's been "a week" since the events of _Civil War_.